# How do I use redex? How often should I use it?

Tags: fuel-additives

Bought some redex "shots" for my 2003 Opel Agila 1.2 petrol.

Do I just fill the tank and then pour it in?

**How do I use it?**

**How often should I use it?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Redex website](https://www.holtsauto.com/redex/products/petrol-one-shot-boot-pack/):

> **How do I use it?**
>
> Simply pour Redex directly into the tank in the same way you add fuel. The bottles have been designed with a long neck which inserts like a fuel pump to make pouring easy.
>
> **How often should I use it?**
>
> Redex can be used as often as you like to keep your engine running well. We recommend using a shot in each tank, but you can also use it whenever you notice your MPG dropping or between fill ups.